# Find words including ":" in a list with Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list which has some words. I want to filter out words including ":".
How can I write a code to separate them from other words?

Comment: `filter(lambda s: ":" not in s, xs)`

Comment: Try looking into regular expressions to identify words containing “:”. Check the Python “re” package in particular.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland While it is possible to do this with regex, you can simply check if a string contains a substring with `substr in str`, which is shorter, easier to read and also executes faster.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch, you're right... if he has a clean Python list like `['word:1', 'word:2', 'word:3']`, it would even be simpler to do `for word in list: if ':' in word...` but the question was not very clear to me when he says "I have a list which has some words...". I was thinking he might need to isolate words which is where regex could be useful I guess

Comment: Thanks all. @N.Wouda sent me a link about laziness. I read it and now I am somehow ashamed. however when I asked this question, I performed many tasks and tried too much. therefore I was tired and when I faced the last error, I got angry and without paying enough attention asked this question immediately. I wrote several lines and  just made a mistake. I called a variable wrong. Jimmy Carlos answer helped me to solve it easily. I apologize all who try to help me again and thanks them. it was my first question and hereafter I will try to be more professional.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension. This can filter all elements of a list based on whether they pass an if statement.

Code:

```
my_list = ["Apples","Bananas","Colons:","CSI:NY","Egbert"]
with_colons = [a for a in my_list if ":" in a]
without_colons = [a for a in my_list if ":" not in a]
print(with_colons)
print(without_colons)
```

Output:

```
['Colons:', 'CSI:NY']
['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Egbert']
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering this list of words there are two possibilities:

```
list_of_words = ['word_without_colon', 'word:with:colon']
```

1. The `filter`-function:

`words_with_colons = list(filter(lambda word: ':' in word, list_of_words))`

2. List comprehensions:

`words_with_colons = [word for word in list_of_words if ':' in word]`

Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, recommends using list comprehensions and even [planned to remove the `filter`-function completely in Python 3](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196):

> I think dropping `filter()` and `map()` is pretty uncontroversial; `filter(P, S)` is almost always written clearer as `[x for x in S if P(x)]`, and this has the huge advantage that the most common usages involve predicates that are comparisons, e.g. `x==42`, and defining a lambda for that just requires much more effort for the reader (plus the lambda is slower than the list comprehension). Even more so for `map(F, S)` which becomes `[F(x) for x in S]`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `filter()`

```
a = ['hello', 'foo:bar', 'baz']
b = list(filter(lambda x: ':' not in x, a))
```